# Missing Class Reference in Yii

Tags: php, yii

As I am studying Yii I keep for looking this class of Yii:app()->**user**
but as I view all the classes below the **Yii::app()** I don't see any class **user**

but this class is always used in the yii tutorials
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.action

sample code is like this

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

and as i browse Yii::app class which is CApplication class I don't see any **user** class.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication

where i should search this **user** class?

I want to learn this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` in here is a [component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component) attached to the application. You can see how application components work in [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-components). You can see the list of core application components in [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#core-application-components). By default, the user component is [`CWebUser`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser).

Answer (score 1):

user is id of component CWebUser.
Look at CWebUser class.